# Ethereum Difficulty History? Percentages not a chart

Tags: mining, difficulty

Is there any website that shows the Ethereum difficulty with percentage increase instead of just a chart ?

I'm looking for something similar to https://bitcoinwisdom.com/bitcoin/difficulty : in the middle of the page there it has a Difficulty History with date/hashrate/change etc...

Answer (score 2):

I've got the following raw data from by viewing the source at https://etherscan.io/charts/difficulty .

```
data: [ {y : 0.121, dt : 'Thursday, July 30, 2015', },{y : 0.603, dt : 'Friday, July 31, 2015', },{y : 0.887, dt : 'Saturday, August 1, 2015', },{y : 1.020, dt : 'Sunday, August 2, 2015', },{y : 1.126, dt : 'Monday, August 3, 2015', },{y : 1.217, dt : 'Tuesday, August 4, 2015', },{y : 1.328, dt : 'Wednesday, August 5, 2015', },{y : 1.381, dt : 'Thursday, August 6, 2015', },{y : 1.471, dt : 'Friday, August 7, 2015', },{y : 1.586, dt : 'Saturday, August 8, 2015', },{y : 1.709, dt : 'Sunday, August 9, 2015', },{y : 1.838, dt : 'Monday, August 10, 2015', },{y : 2.036, dt : 'Tuesday, August 11, 2015', },{y : 2.207, dt : 'Wednesday, August 12, 2015', },{y : 2.337, dt : 'Thursday, August 13, 2015', },{y : 2.671, dt : 'Friday, August 14, 2015', },{y : 3.378, dt : 'Saturday, August 15, 2015', },{y : 3.632, dt : 'Sunday, August 16, 2015', },{y : 3.908, dt : 'Monday, August 17, 2015', },{y : 4.378, dt : 'Tuesday, August 18, 2015', },{y : 4.420, dt : 'Wednesday, August 19, 2015', },{y : 4.469, dt : 'Thursday, August 20, 2015', },{y : 4.415, dt : 'Friday, August 21, 2015', },{y : 4.828, dt : 'Saturday, August 22, 2015', },{y : 5.138, dt : 'Sunday, August 23, 2015', },{y : 5.179, dt : 'Monday, August 24, 2015', },{y : 5.173, dt : 'Tuesday, August 25, 2015', },{y : 5.587, dt : 'Wednesday, August 26, 2015', },{y : 5.925, dt : 'Thursday, August 27, 2015', },{y : 6.251, dt : 'Friday, August 28, 2015', },{y : 6.658, dt : 'Saturday, August 29, 2015', },{y : 6.781, dt : 'Sunday, August 30, 2015', },{y : 7.214, dt : 'Monday, August 31, 2015', },{y : 7.641, dt : 'Tuesday, September 1, 2015', },{y : 8.284, dt : 'Wednesday, September 2, 2015', },{y : 8.355, dt : 'Thursday, September 3, 2015', },{y : 6.470, dt : 'Friday, September 4, 2015', },{y : 6.235, dt : 'Saturday, September 5, 2015', },{y : 6.305, dt : 'Sunday, September 6, 2015', },{y : 6.339, dt : 'Monday, September 7, 2015', },{y : 6.077, dt : 'Tuesday, September 8, 2015', },{y : 6.202, dt : 'Wednesday, September 9, 2015', },{y : 6.290, dt : 'Thursday, September 10, 2015', },{y : 6.562, dt : 'Friday, September 11, 2015', },{y : 6.833, dt : 'Saturday, September 12, 2015', },{y : 7.022, dt : 'Sunday, September 13, 2015', },{y : 6.626, dt : 'Monday, September 14, 2015', },{y : 6.419, dt : 'Tuesday, September 15, 2015', },{y : 6.179, dt : 'Wednesday, September 16, 2015', },{y : 6.040, dt : 'Thursday, September 17, 2015', },{y : 5.653, dt : 'Friday, September 18, 2015', },{y : 5.548, dt : 'Saturday, September 19, 2015', },{y : 6.202, dt : 'Sunday, September 20, 2015', },{y : 6.541, dt : 'Monday, September 21, 2015', },{y : 6.624, dt : 'Tuesday, September 22, 2015', },{y : 6.895, dt : 'Wednesday, September 23, 2015', },{y : 7.029, dt : 'Thursday, September 24, 2015', },{y : 6.977, dt : 'Friday, September 25, 2015', },{y : 7.227, dt : 'Saturday, September 26, 2015', },{y : 7.253, dt : 'Sunday, September 27, 2015', },{y : 6.747, dt : 'Monday, September 28, 2015', },{y : 6.057, dt : 'Tuesday, September 29, 2015', },{y : 5.625, dt : 'Wednesday, September 30, 2015', },{y : 5.653, dt : 'Thursday, October 1, 2015', },{y : 5.982, dt : 'Friday, October 2, 2015', },{y : 6.291, dt : 'Saturday, October 3, 2015', },{y : 6.206, dt : 'Sunday, October 4, 2015', },{y : 6.285, dt : 'Monday, October 5, 2015', },{y : 6.276, dt : 'Tuesday, October 6, 2015', },{y : 5.984, dt : 'Wednesday, October 7, 2015', },{y : 5.978, dt : 'Thursday, October 8, 2015', },{y : 6.123, dt : 'Friday, October 9, 2015', },{y : 6.032, dt : 'Saturday, October 10, 2015', },{y : 6.139, dt : 'Sunday, October 11, 2015', },{y : 6.145, dt : 'Monday, October 12, 2015', },{y : 6.357, dt : 'Tuesday, October 13, 2015', },{y : 6.482, dt : 'Wednesday, October 14, 2015', },{y : 6.209, dt : 'Thursday, October 15, 2015', },{y : 5.815, dt : 'Friday, October 16, 2015', },{y : 6.004, dt : 'Saturday, October 17, 2015', },{y : 5.974, dt : 'Sunday, October 18, 2015', },{y : 5.922, dt : 'Monday, October 19, 2015', },{y : 5.835, dt : 'Tuesday, October 20, 2015', },{y : 5.876, dt : 'Wednesday, October 21, 2015', },{y : 5.734, dt : 'Thursday, October 22, 2015', },{y : 5.879, dt : 'Friday, October 23, 2015', },{y : 6.288, dt : 'Saturday, October 24, 2015', },{y : 6.589, dt : 'Sunday, October 25, 2015', },{y : 6.541, dt : 'Monday, October 26, 2015', },{y : 6.542, dt : 'Tuesday, October 27, 2015', },{y : 6.846, dt : 'Wednesday, October 28, 2015', },{y : 7.040, dt : 'Thursday, October 29, 2015', },{y : 7.429, dt : 'Friday, October 30, 2015', },{y : 7.793, dt : 'Saturday, October 31, 2015', },{y : 7.781, dt : 'Sunday, November 1, 2015', },{y : 7.690, dt : 'Monday, November 2, 2015', },{y : 7.333, dt : 'Tuesday, November 3, 2015', },{y : 7.743, dt : 'Wednesday, November 4, 2015', },{y : 7.582, dt : 'Thursday, November 5, 2015', },{y : 7.592, dt : 'Friday, November 6, 2015', },{y : 7.550, dt : 'Saturday, November 7, 2015', },{y : 7.709, dt : 'Sunday, November 8, 2015', },{y : 7.754, dt : 'Monday, November 9, 2015', },{y : 7.760, dt : 'Tuesday, November 10, 2015', },{y : 7.673, dt : 'Wednesday, November 11, 2015', },{y : 7.746, dt : 'Thursday, November 12, 2015', },{y : 7.870, dt : 'Friday, November 13, 2015', },{y : 7.913, dt : 'Saturday, November 14, 2015', },{y : 8.260, dt : 'Sunday, November 15, 2015', },{y : 8.327, dt : 'Monday, November 16, 2015', },{y : 8.153, dt : 'Tuesday, November 17, 2015', },{y : 8.550, dt : 'Wednesday, November 18, 2015', },{y : 8.807, dt : 'Thursday, November 19, 2015', },{y : 7.975, dt : 'Friday, November 20, 2015', },{y : 7.601, dt : 'Saturday, November 21, 2015', },{y : 7.533, dt : 'Sunday, November 22, 2015', },{y : 7.566, dt : 'Monday, November 23, 2015', },{y : 7.665, dt : 'Tuesday, November 24, 2015', },{y : 7.517, dt : 'Wednesday, November 25, 2015', },{y : 7.498, dt : 'Thursday, November 26, 2015', },{y : 7.470, dt : 'Friday, November 27, 2015', },{y : 7.721, dt : 'Saturday, November 28, 2015', },{y : 7.721, dt : 'Sunday, November 29, 2015', },{y : 7.781, dt : 'Monday, November 30, 2015', },{y : 7.873, dt : 'Tuesday, December 1, 2015', },{y : 7.818, dt : 'Wednesday, December 2, 2015', },{y : 7.588, dt : 'Thursday, December 3, 2015', },{y : 7.833, dt : 'Friday, December 4, 2015', },{y : 8.164, dt : 'Saturday, December 5, 2015', },{y : 7.852, dt : 'Sunday, December 6, 2015', },{y : 7.648, dt : 'Monday, December 7, 2015', },{y : 7.548, dt : 'Tuesday, December 8, 2015', },{y : 7.350, dt : 'Wednesday, December 9, 2015', },{y : 7.773, dt : 'Thursday, December 10, 2015', },{y : 8.060, dt : 'Friday, December 11, 2015', },{y : 8.045, dt : 'Saturday, December 12, 2015', },{y : 8.472, dt : 'Sunday, December 13, 2015', },{y : 8.576, dt : 'Monday, December 14, 2015', },{y : 8.769, dt : 'Tuesday, December 15, 2015', },{y : 8.562, dt : 'Wednesday, December 16, 2015', },{y : 8.734, dt : 'Thursday, December 17, 2015', },{y : 8.780, dt : 'Friday, December 18, 2015', },{y : 8.719, dt : 'Saturday, December 19, 2015', },{y : 8.540, dt : 'Sunday, December 20, 2015', },{y : 8.513, dt : 'Monday, December 21, 2015', },{y : 8.740, dt : 'Tuesday, December 22, 2015', },{y : 8.532, dt : 'Wednesday, December 23, 2015', },{y : 8.569, dt : 'Thursday, December 24, 2015', },{y : 8.546, dt : 'Friday, December 25, 2015', },{y : 8.456, dt : 'Saturday, December 26, 2015', },{y : 8.589, dt : 'Sunday, December 27, 2015', },{y : 8.532, dt : 'Monday, December 28, 2015', },{y : 8.605, dt : 'Tuesday, December 29, 2015', },{y : 8.478, dt : 'Wednesday, December 30, 2015', },{y : 8.543, dt : 'Thursday, December 31, 2015', },{y : 8.547, dt : 'Friday, January 1, 2016', },{y : 8.147, dt : 'Saturday, January 2, 2016', },{y : 8.312, dt : 'Sunday, January 3, 2016', },{y : 8.334, dt : 'Monday, January 4, 2016', },{y : 8.306, dt : 'Tuesday, January 5, 2016', },{y : 8.423, dt : 'Wednesday, January 6, 2016', },{y : 8.210, dt : 'Thursday, January 7, 2016', },{y : 8.302, dt : 'Friday, January 8, 2016', },{y : 8.433, dt : 'Saturday, January 9, 2016', },{y : 8.337, dt : 'Sunday, January 10, 2016', },{y : 8.828, dt : 'Monday, January 11, 2016', },{y : 8.890, dt : 'Tuesday, January 12, 2016', },{y : 8.484, dt : 'Wednesday, January 13, 2016', },{y : 8.735, dt : 'Thursday, January 14, 2016', },{y : 8.996, dt : 'Friday, January 15, 2016', },{y : 9.202, dt : 'Saturday, January 16, 2016', },{y : 9.068, dt : 'Sunday, January 17, 2016', },{y : 9.454, dt : 'Monday, January 18, 2016', },{y : 9.539, dt : 'Tuesday, January 19, 2016', },{y : 9.414, dt : 'Wednesday, January 20, 2016', },{y : 9.598, dt : 'Thursday, January 21, 2016', },{y : 9.897, dt : 'Friday, January 22, 2016', },{y : 10.059, dt : 'Saturday, January 23, 2016', },{y : 10.133, dt : 'Sunday, January 24, 2016', },{y : 10.330, dt : 'Monday, January 25, 2016', },{y : 10.611, dt : 'Tuesday, January 26, 2016', },{y : 10.820, dt : 'Wednesday, January 27, 2016', },{y : 10.449, dt : 'Thursday, January 28, 2016', },{y : 10.883, dt : 'Friday, January 29, 2016', },{y : 10.876, dt : 'Saturday, January 30, 2016', },{y : 10.696, dt : 'Sunday, January 31, 2016', },{y : 10.917, dt : 'Monday, February 1, 2016', },{y : 10.674, dt : 'Tuesday, February 2, 2016', },{y : 10.857, dt : 'Wednesday, February 3, 2016', },{y : 11.114, dt : 'Thursday, February 4, 2016', },{y : 11.176, dt : 'Friday, February 5, 2016', },{y : 10.867, dt : 'Saturday, February 6, 2016', },{y : 11.050, dt : 'Sunday, February 7, 2016', },{y : 11.540, dt : 'Monday, February 8, 2016', },{y : 11.245, dt : 'Tuesday, February 9, 2016', },{y : 11.659, dt : 'Wednesday, February 10, 2016', },{y : 11.994, dt : 'Thursday, February 11, 2016', },{y : 11.553, dt : 'Friday, February 12, 2016', },{y : 12.097, dt : 'Saturday, February 13, 2016', },{y : 12.497, dt : 'Sunday, February 14, 2016', },{y : 12.875, dt : 'Monday, February 15, 2016', },{y : 12.696, dt : 'Tuesday, February 16, 2016', },{y : 12.722, dt : 'Wednesday, February 17, 2016', },{y : 12.182, dt : 'Thursday, February 18, 2016', },{y : 12.651, dt : 'Friday, February 19, 2016', },{y : 12.814, dt : 'Saturday, February 20, 2016', },{y : 12.959, dt : 'Sunday, February 21, 2016', },{y : 13.432, dt : 'Monday, February 22, 2016', },{y : 13.784, dt : 'Tuesday, February 23, 2016', },{y : 13.623, dt : 'Wednesday, February 24, 2016', },{y : 13.574, dt : 'Thursday, February 25, 2016', },{y : 14.049, dt : 'Friday, February 26, 2016', },{y : 14.565, dt : 'Saturday, February 27, 2016', },{y : 14.737, dt : 'Sunday, February 28, 2016', },{y : 14.937, dt : 'Monday, February 29, 2016', },{y : 14.453, dt : 'Tuesday, March 1, 2016', },{y : 14.990, dt : 'Wednesday, March 2, 2016', },{y : 15.599, dt : 'Thursday, March 3, 2016', },{y : 16.141, dt : 'Friday, March 4, 2016', },{y : 16.473, dt : 'Saturday, March 5, 2016', },{y : 17.342, dt : 'Sunday, March 6, 2016', },{y : 17.164, dt : 'Monday, March 7, 2016', },{y : 17.492, dt : 'Tuesday, March 8, 2016', },{y : 17.867, dt : 'Wednesday, March 9, 2016', },{y : 18.006, dt : 'Thursday, March 10, 2016', },{y : 18.682, dt : 'Friday, March 11, 2016', },{y : 19.655, dt : 'Saturday, March 12, 2016', },{y : 20.150, dt : 'Sunday, March 13, 2016', },{y : 20.066, dt : 'Monday, March 14, 2016', },{y : 17.572, dt : 'Tuesday, March 15, 2016', },{y : 17.778, dt : 'Wednesday, March 16, 2016', },{y : 18.039, dt : 'Thursday, March 17, 2016', },{y : 18.300, dt : 'Friday, March 18, 2016', },{y : 18.652, dt : 'Saturday, March 19, 2016', },{y : 19.423, dt : 'Sunday, March 20, 2016', },{y : 19.269, dt : 'Monday, March 21, 2016', },{y : 19.568, dt : 'Tuesday, March 22, 2016', },{y : 18.766, dt : 'Wednesday, March 23, 2016', },{y : 19.801, dt : 'Thursday, March 24, 2016', },{y : 20.872, dt : 'Friday, March 25, 2016', },{y : 21.414, dt : 'Saturday, March 26, 2016', },{y : 21.977, dt : 'Sunday, March 27, 2016', },{y : 21.768, dt : 'Monday, March 28, 2016', },{y : 22.514, dt : 'Tuesday, March 29, 2016', },{y : 22.822, dt : 'Wednesday, March 30, 2016', },{y : 23.889, dt : 'Thursday, March 31, 2016', },]
```

And here's the hashrate data from https://etherscan.io/charts/hashrate:

```
data: [ {y : 23.7569, dt : 'Thursday, July 30, 2015', },{y : 48.1584, dt : 'Friday, July 31, 2015', },{y : 55.2709, dt : 'Saturday, August 1, 2015', },{y : 64.1779, dt : 'Sunday, August 2, 2015', },{y : 69.8559, dt : 'Monday, August 3, 2015', },{y : 76.6115, dt : 'Tuesday, August 4, 2015', },{y : 81.9449, dt : 'Wednesday, August 5, 2015', },{y : 82.9366, dt : 'Thursday, August 6, 2015', },{y : 89.6063, dt : 'Friday, August 7, 2015', },{y : 97.6083, dt : 'Saturday, August 8, 2015', },{y : 102.5407, dt : 'Sunday, August 9, 2015', },{y : 113.1109, dt : 'Monday, August 10, 2015', },{y : 126.6631, dt : 'Tuesday, August 11, 2015', },{y : 132.7661, dt : 'Wednesday, August 12, 2015', },{y : 144.8995, dt : 'Thursday, August 13, 2015', },{y : 183.5527, dt : 'Friday, August 14, 2015', },{y : 213.9622, dt : 'Saturday, August 15, 2015', },{y : 220.8548, dt : 'Sunday, August 16, 2015', },{y : 245.4865, dt : 'Monday, August 17, 2015', },{y : 253.7123, dt : 'Tuesday, August 18, 2015', },{y : 269.2527, dt : 'Wednesday, August 19, 2015', },{y : 252.3917, dt : 'Thursday, August 20, 2015', },{y : 263.4014, dt : 'Friday, August 21, 2015', },{y : 298.2545, dt : 'Saturday, August 22, 2015', },{y : 303.0820, dt : 'Sunday, August 23, 2015', },{y : 314.6624, dt : 'Monday, August 24, 2015', },{y : 309.2154, dt : 'Tuesday, August 25, 2015', },{y : 327.8673, dt : 'Wednesday, August 26, 2015', },{y : 327.6196, dt : 'Thursday, August 27, 2015', },{y : 340.1254, dt : 'Friday, August 28, 2015', },{y : 339.3919, dt : 'Saturday, August 29, 2015', },{y : 332.4474, dt : 'Sunday, August 30, 2015', },{y : 351.2291, dt : 'Monday, August 31, 2015', },{y : 354.1181, dt : 'Tuesday, September 1, 2015', },{y : 349.6263, dt : 'Wednesday, September 2, 2015', },{y : 331.5756, dt : 'Thursday, September 3, 2015', },{y : 340.3879, dt : 'Friday, September 4, 2015', },{y : 361.5994, dt : 'Saturday, September 5, 2015', },{y : 371.3126, dt : 'Sunday, September 6, 2015', },{y : 360.9598, dt : 'Monday, September 7, 2015', },{y : 352.7229, dt : 'Tuesday, September 8, 2015', },{y : 368.0392, dt : 'Wednesday, September 9, 2015', },{y : 371.1206, dt : 'Thursday, September 10, 2015', },{y : 397.2576, dt : 'Friday, September 11, 2015', },{y : 405.6008, dt : 'Saturday, September 12, 2015', },{y : 412.3321, dt : 'Sunday, September 13, 2015', },{y : 380.4038, dt : 'Monday, September 14, 2015', },{y : 366.6357, dt : 'Tuesday, September 15, 2015', },{y : 362.0796, dt : 'Wednesday, September 16, 2015', },{y : 342.0493, dt : 'Thursday, September 17, 2015', },{y : 326.1315, dt : 'Friday, September 18, 2015', },{y : 332.9998, dt : 'Saturday, September 19, 2015', },{y : 390.7766, dt : 'Sunday, September 20, 2015', },{y : 393.8171, dt : 'Monday, September 21, 2015', },{y : 395.4227, dt : 'Tuesday, September 22, 2015', },{y : 422.5629, dt : 'Wednesday, September 23, 2015', },{y : 417.5910, dt : 'Thursday, September 24, 2015', },{y : 421.4033, dt : 'Friday, September 25, 2015', },{y : 423.4245, dt : 'Saturday, September 26, 2015', },{y : 412.8378, dt : 'Sunday, September 27, 2015', },{y : 379.0354, dt : 'Monday, September 28, 2015', },{y : 330.5963, dt : 'Tuesday, September 29, 2015', },{y : 315.1845, dt : 'Wednesday, September 30, 2015', },{y : 347.9262, dt : 'Thursday, October 1, 2015', },{y : 364.9391, dt : 'Friday, October 2, 2015', },{y : 378.3587, dt : 'Saturday, October 3, 2015', },{y : 360.3209, dt : 'Sunday, October 4, 2015', },{y : 373.8427, dt : 'Monday, October 5, 2015', },{y : 361.6866, dt : 'Tuesday, October 6, 2015', },{y : 354.5899, dt : 'Wednesday, October 7, 2015', },{y : 364.4138, dt : 'Thursday, October 8, 2015', },{y : 355.5959, dt : 'Friday, October 9, 2015', },{y : 351.0840, dt : 'Saturday, October 10, 2015', },{y : 368.0058, dt : 'Sunday, October 11, 2015', },{y : 378.7687, dt : 'Monday, October 12, 2015', },{y : 384.9138, dt : 'Tuesday, October 13, 2015', },{y : 379.3914, dt : 'Wednesday, October 14, 2015', },{y : 361.6693, dt : 'Thursday, October 15, 2015', },{y : 336.9025, dt : 'Friday, October 16, 2015', },{y : 360.0608, dt : 'Saturday, October 17, 2015', },{y : 349.8902, dt : 'Sunday, October 18, 2015', },{y : 347.3344, dt : 'Monday, October 19, 2015', },{y : 343.9115, dt : 'Tuesday, October 20, 2015', },{y : 346.8015, dt : 'Wednesday, October 21, 2015', },{y : 326.6268, dt : 'Thursday, October 22, 2015', },{y : 365.8809, dt : 'Friday, October 23, 2015', },{y : 387.2388, dt : 'Saturday, October 24, 2015', },{y : 399.0500, dt : 'Sunday, October 25, 2015', },{y : 379.5194, dt : 'Monday, October 26, 2015', },{y : 402.6895, dt : 'Tuesday, October 27, 2015', },{y : 399.8592, dt : 'Wednesday, October 28, 2015', },{y : 428.9193, dt : 'Thursday, October 29, 2015', },{y : 461.8848, dt : 'Friday, October 30, 2015', },{y : 474.3059, dt : 'Saturday, October 31, 2015', },{y : 475.3902, dt : 'Sunday, November 1, 2015', },{y : 458.2611, dt : 'Monday, November 2, 2015', },{y : 441.5678, dt : 'Tuesday, November 3, 2015', },{y : 465.7518, dt : 'Wednesday, November 4, 2015', },{y : 455.3749, dt : 'Thursday, November 5, 2015', },{y : 464.8882, dt : 'Friday, November 6, 2015', },{y : 443.1504, dt : 'Saturday, November 7, 2015', },{y : 459.0328, dt : 'Sunday, November 8, 2015', },{y : 461.3202, dt : 'Monday, November 9, 2015', },{y : 463.7579, dt : 'Tuesday, November 10, 2015', },{y : 454.7690, dt : 'Wednesday, November 11, 2015', },{y : 465.8401, dt : 'Thursday, November 12, 2015', },{y : 479.0797, dt : 'Friday, November 13, 2015', },{y : 481.9432, dt : 'Saturday, November 14, 2015', },{y : 505.8890, dt : 'Sunday, November 15, 2015', },{y : 499.1223, dt : 'Monday, November 16, 2015', },{y : 500.6890, dt : 'Tuesday, November 17, 2015', },{y : 515.9244, dt : 'Wednesday, November 18, 2015', },{y : 527.3325, dt : 'Thursday, November 19, 2015', },{y : 444.6029, dt : 'Friday, November 20, 2015', },{y : 452.9449, dt : 'Saturday, November 21, 2015', },{y : 453.2137, dt : 'Sunday, November 22, 2015', },{y : 460.4471, dt : 'Monday, November 23, 2015', },{y : 451.9348, dt : 'Tuesday, November 24, 2015', },{y : 437.6937, dt : 'Wednesday, November 25, 2015', },{y : 440.4046, dt : 'Thursday, November 26, 2015', },{y : 458.0060, dt : 'Friday, November 27, 2015', },{y : 460.0296, dt : 'Saturday, November 28, 2015', },{y : 467.2217, dt : 'Sunday, November 29, 2015', },{y : 470.9538, dt : 'Monday, November 30, 2015', },{y : 470.8828, dt : 'Tuesday, December 1, 2015', },{y : 446.5842, dt : 'Wednesday, December 2, 2015', },{y : 465.4228, dt : 'Thursday, December 3, 2015', },{y : 464.7690, dt : 'Friday, December 4, 2015', },{y : 484.0832, dt : 'Saturday, December 5, 2015', },{y : 456.1653, dt : 'Sunday, December 6, 2015', },{y : 451.5806, dt : 'Monday, December 7, 2015', },{y : 440.4392, dt : 'Tuesday, December 8, 2015', },{y : 451.5592, dt : 'Wednesday, December 9, 2015', },{y : 472.5491, dt : 'Thursday, December 10, 2015', },{y : 482.2872, dt : 'Friday, December 11, 2015', },{y : 485.3189, dt : 'Saturday, December 12, 2015', },{y : 527.4325, dt : 'Sunday, December 13, 2015', },{y : 507.6232, dt : 'Monday, December 14, 2015', },{y : 525.7241, dt : 'Tuesday, December 15, 2015', },{y : 507.0430, dt : 'Wednesday, December 16, 2015', },{y : 525.5147, dt : 'Thursday, December 17, 2015', },{y : 521.9400, dt : 'Friday, December 18, 2015', },{y : 521.0237, dt : 'Saturday, December 19, 2015', },{y : 508.7178, dt : 'Sunday, December 20, 2015', },{y : 503.4873, dt : 'Monday, December 21, 2015', },{y : 532.5519, dt : 'Tuesday, December 22, 2015', },{y : 515.6242, dt : 'Wednesday, December 23, 2015', },{y : 510.9724, dt : 'Thursday, December 24, 2015', },{y : 513.0784, dt : 'Friday, December 25, 2015', },{y : 503.1197, dt : 'Saturday, December 26, 2015', },{y : 513.1455, dt : 'Sunday, December 27, 2015', },{y : 519.2876, dt : 'Monday, December 28, 2015', },{y : 507.0365, dt : 'Tuesday, December 29, 2015', },{y : 505.9181, dt : 'Wednesday, December 30, 2015', },{y : 511.0014, dt : 'Thursday, December 31, 2015', },{y : 498.5749, dt : 'Friday, January 1, 2016', },{y : 492.1201, dt : 'Saturday, January 2, 2016', },{y : 509.4547, dt : 'Sunday, January 3, 2016', },{y : 508.1827, dt : 'Monday, January 4, 2016', },{y : 513.2618, dt : 'Tuesday, January 5, 2016', },{y : 513.8092, dt : 'Wednesday, January 6, 2016', },{y : 490.9855, dt : 'Thursday, January 7, 2016', },{y : 516.4913, dt : 'Friday, January 8, 2016', },{y : 514.4362, dt : 'Saturday, January 9, 2016', },{y : 510.7642, dt : 'Sunday, January 10, 2016', },{y : 541.9062, dt : 'Monday, January 11, 2016', },{y : 522.5879, dt : 'Tuesday, January 12, 2016', },{y : 508.8842, dt : 'Wednesday, January 13, 2016', },{y : 532.0852, dt : 'Thursday, January 14, 2016', },{y : 550.7681, dt : 'Friday, January 15, 2016', },{y : 557.6853, dt : 'Saturday, January 16, 2016', },{y : 548.1829, dt : 'Sunday, January 17, 2016', },{y : 575.3153, dt : 'Monday, January 18, 2016', },{y : 572.2182, dt : 'Tuesday, January 19, 2016', },{y : 572.1047, dt : 'Wednesday, January 20, 2016', },{y : 573.7090, dt : 'Thursday, January 21, 2016', },{y : 597.3168, dt : 'Friday, January 22, 2016', },{y : 596.8191, dt : 'Saturday, January 23, 2016', },{y : 628.6510, dt : 'Sunday, January 24, 2016', },{y : 605.5737, dt : 'Monday, January 25, 2016', },{y : 658.7338, dt : 'Tuesday, January 26, 2016', },{y : 647.7358, dt : 'Wednesday, January 27, 2016', },{y : 624.3007, dt : 'Thursday, January 28, 2016', },{y : 639.9955, dt : 'Friday, January 29, 2016', },{y : 647.0259, dt : 'Saturday, January 30, 2016', },{y : 615.8746, dt : 'Sunday, January 31, 2016', },{y : 654.1278, dt : 'Monday, February 1, 2016', },{y : 630.3772, dt : 'Tuesday, February 2, 2016', },{y : 672.6015, dt : 'Wednesday, February 3, 2016', },{y : 670.9910, dt : 'Thursday, February 4, 2016', },{y : 670.5626, dt : 'Friday, February 5, 2016', },{y : 647.0863, dt : 'Saturday, February 6, 2016', },{y : 670.8703, dt : 'Sunday, February 7, 2016', },{y : 700.3927, dt : 'Monday, February 8, 2016', },{y : 674.4033, dt : 'Tuesday, February 9, 2016', },{y : 686.6895, dt : 'Wednesday, February 10, 2016', },{y : 715.5490, dt : 'Thursday, February 11, 2016', },{y : 689.2240, dt : 'Friday, February 12, 2016', },{y : 728.3101, dt : 'Saturday, February 13, 2016', },{y : 744.6017, dt : 'Sunday, February 14, 2016', },{y : 760.8675, dt : 'Monday, February 15, 2016', },{y : 758.1305, dt : 'Tuesday, February 16, 2016', },{y : 737.5344, dt : 'Wednesday, February 17, 2016', },{y : 723.4539, dt : 'Thursday, February 18, 2016', },{y : 758.4649, dt : 'Friday, February 19, 2016', },{y : 772.5410, dt : 'Saturday, February 20, 2016', },{y : 776.9570, dt : 'Sunday, February 21, 2016', },{y : 818.0979, dt : 'Monday, February 22, 2016', },{y : 822.7791, dt : 'Tuesday, February 23, 2016', },{y : 822.5628, dt : 'Wednesday, February 24, 2016', },{y : 833.5308, dt : 'Thursday, February 25, 2016', },{y : 851.8002, dt : 'Friday, February 26, 2016', },{y : 871.6768, dt : 'Saturday, February 27, 2016', },{y : 889.7172, dt : 'Sunday, February 28, 2016', },{y : 868.4570, dt : 'Monday, February 29, 2016', },{y : 887.5800, dt : 'Tuesday, March 1, 2016', },{y : 915.7752, dt : 'Wednesday, March 2, 2016', },{y : 945.4459, dt : 'Thursday, March 3, 2016', },{y : 970.9779, dt : 'Friday, March 4, 2016', },{y : 1022.7687, dt : 'Saturday, March 5, 2016', },{y : 1030.5122, dt : 'Sunday, March 6, 2016', },{y : 1037.0411, dt : 'Monday, March 7, 2016', },{y : 1054.0514, dt : 'Tuesday, March 8, 2016', },{y : 1074.1375, dt : 'Wednesday, March 9, 2016', },{y : 1131.0236, dt : 'Thursday, March 10, 2016', },{y : 1135.2724, dt : 'Friday, March 11, 2016', },{y : 1189.2959, dt : 'Saturday, March 12, 2016', },{y : 1270.7701, dt : 'Sunday, March 13, 2016', },{y : 1231.9938, dt : 'Monday, March 14, 2016', },{y : 1259.5857, dt : 'Tuesday, March 15, 2016', },{y : 1285.0031, dt : 'Wednesday, March 16, 2016', },{y : 1325.0584, dt : 'Thursday, March 17, 2016', },{y : 1327.0590, dt : 'Friday, March 18, 2016', },{y : 1376.7015, dt : 'Saturday, March 19, 2016', },{y : 1413.2109, dt : 'Sunday, March 20, 2016', },{y : 1392.9337, dt : 'Monday, March 21, 2016', },{y : 1431.5834, dt : 'Tuesday, March 22, 2016', },{y : 1354.1250, dt : 'Wednesday, March 23, 2016', },{y : 1465.4863, dt : 'Thursday, March 24, 2016', },{y : 1533.2559, dt : 'Friday, March 25, 2016', },{y : 1580.9776, dt : 'Saturday, March 26, 2016', },{y : 1607.1295, dt : 'Sunday, March 27, 2016', },{y : 1572.9770, dt : 'Monday, March 28, 2016', },{y : 1640.0171, dt : 'Tuesday, March 29, 2016', },{y : 1661.3373, dt : 'Wednesday, March 30, 2016', },{y : 1740.8734, dt : 'Thursday, March 31, 2016', },]
```