# Excel sheet of difficulty hash of Ethereum

Tags: ethereum-classic

I am trying to acquire an excel spreadsheet or csv file with the daily or weekly historical difficulty rate of ETH or ETC. Can you please make  a suggestion on how I can get that information?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Related: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2526/ethereum-difficulty-history-percentages-not-a-chart

Answer (score 2):

A quick google search gave me these links

http://www.coinwarz.com/difficulty-charts/ethereum-difficulty-chart

https://etherscan.io/chart/difficulty

Now, if you want to keep your own stats, is as easy as having a full synchronised node, and get, for each block, its `difficulty` field.

Answer (score 1):

To add to the first answer...

On the https://etherscan.io/chart/difficulty, at the bottom right of the chart picture, there's a [CSV Data](https://etherscan.io/chart/difficulty?output=csv) link.

(I think this verges on a duplication of the following previous question: [Ethereum Difficulty History? Percentages not a chart](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2526/ethereum-difficulty-history-percentages-not-a-chart). Feel free to flag as such.)